# Logical approach to navigation and flatlist

Tags: react-native

I click on a button on one screen which loads another screen with a flat list which renders many rows. My conundrum is that I hang on the first screen while the flatlist processes.

My best effort so far is a loader, hidden this.props.children to process the flatlist, then hide the loader and show this.props.children again.

I'm sure there must be a more logical approach?

Ta,

Chris

Comment: Please provide some example code and/or what approaches you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

- first instead ho hiding flatlist and  showing loader you can use
  Refresh Control from React-native. which will we do the same same job
  with ease.
- second if your list is long you can lazy load your data by using onEndReached Callback this will decrease the loading time .
- third make your renderComponent in flatlist a pure Component .which will  stop unecessary refreshes and increase performance.

  check the code below .....

```js
         <FlatList
            data={this.props.questions}
            renderItem={({ item, index }) => <QuestionCard              //your pure component 
              item={item}
              index={index}
              onPress={this.openQuestionDetail}
            />
            }

            ref={'flatlist'}
            refreshControl={
              <RefreshControl                                //imported from react-native
                refreshing={isFetching}                  //used to show loader while loading
                onRefresh={this.fetchQuestions}
                title="Pull to refresh"
                tintColor="#fff"
                titleColor="#fff"
                colors={[Colors.secondary_button]}
              />
            }
            onEndReached={this.handleDynamicLoading}     //callback for lazyloading
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.5}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.qid}
          />
```

hope this helps... :)

Comment: thank you...I'm going to start by trying your pure component approach and see how it impacts performance.